# Class not loaded

Tags: html, css, email

I have an CSS style  in an external file and the element refers to a the style using the 'class' attribute.

However, I can't seem to get the styling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email is notorious for being difficult to style  in multiple clients.

For this reason, inline styles and tables are the norm for email templates.

As for loading an external asset, a lot of email clients won't do this for privacy reasons, to prevent the sender from determining if the email has been read by attaching a unique identifier to the URL.

#### Example

```
http://example.com/assets/style.css?nonce=ac77f909
```

The system then checks the nonce against who it maps to, and can tell who is receiving/reading the email.

This is very useful for spammers.

Answer (score 0):

No, most mail clients do not allow external stylesheets. Essentially, your HTML page is stripped of everything but the `body` content. Inline styles will work however.

References and tips:

- http://blog.mailchimp.com/background-images-and-css-in-html-email/
- http://groundwire.org/support/articles/css-and-email-newsletters

Answer (score 0):

Many clients refuse to load external CSS and scripts. Among other things, they'd allow you to track users opening e-mails, which'd be a privacy issue.

Campaign Monitor has a [great, comprehensive set of resources and templates](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/) for designing for e-mail clients.

Comment: "Many clients refuse to load external CSS and scripts." Certainly true for CSS, but are there ANY clients that load scripts in emails? My understanding was that it was universally verboten for security reasons.

Comment: I'm sure there's an edge case or two.